# Doctrine - conditional andWhere in query

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I want to bind a condition in my function. I have a function MarketersGet which give me marketers name . Here is my code :

```
public function MarketersGet(string $marketerId = ''):array
{
    $marketerId = (int)$marketerId;
    $userRoles = config('constantTypes.blah');
    $marketerRole = $userRoles['MARKETER'];

    $userRepository = App::make( DoctrineUserRepo::class );
    $result = $userRepository
        ->selectFrom(' model ')
        ->where(' model.rolesRole = '.$marketerRole)            
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        $marketers = [];
    foreach ($result as $user) {
        $marketers[] = [
            'name' => $user->getUserName(),
            'id' => $user->getId()
        ];
    }

    return $marketers;
}
```

I want to conditional on *$marketerId*, if it has value I added

```
->andWhere(' model.id = '.$marketerId)
```

I tried like this :

```
  $result = $userRepository
        ->selectFrom(' model ')
        ->where(' model.rolesRole = '.$marketerRole);
        if ($marketerId != '')
            $result->andWhere(' model.id = '.$marketerId);
        $result->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Above result is :

```
[]
No Properties
```

Actually if I put andWhere in default query like this :

```
    $result = $userRepository
        ->selectFrom(' model ')
        ->where(' model.rolesRole = '.$marketerRole)
        ->andWhere(' model.id = '.$marketerId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Real result would be like this :

```
{name: "blah blah", id: 28}
```

Surely my conditional query is false , Any suggestion to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

No way to tell if this might make any difference but you might try it:

```
    $result  = $userRepository
                ->selectFrom(' model ')
                ->where(' model.rolesRole = '. $marketerRole);

    if( isset($marketerId) && $marketerId){
        $result->where(' model.id = '.$marketerId);
    }
    $result->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach. If marketedId is empty string - andWhere has no effect. It always passing. But if it has value then model.id condition is checked.

```
$result = $userRepository
    ->selectFrom(' model ')
    ->where(' model.rolesRole = '.$marketerRole)
    ->andWhere(':marketerId = "''" OR model.id = :marketerId')
    ->setParameter('marketerId', $marketerId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```